# C++ Heap Corruption but only in Unit Test Project

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, heap-corruption

I am implementing a custom stack with templating. But I've ran into a problem making me questioning the memory safety. The destructor works fine when normally used, but will trigger a heap corruption when being unit test. Specifically on tests that expect an exception to be thrown.

All the stack code.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "StackOverflowException.h"
#include "StackEmptyException.h"

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    const static int MAX_SIZE = 1000;

    Stack() : m_array(new T[MAX_SIZE]), m_size(0), m_top(0) {};
    Stack(const Stack<T>& _other)
    {
        m_array = new T[MAX_SIZE];
        for(auto i = 0; i < _other.size(); ++i)
        {
            m_array[i] = _other.m_array[i];
        }
        m_size = _other.size();
        m_top = _other.m_top;
    }

    ~Stack()
    {
        delete[] m_array;
    }

    void push(T _item)
    {
        if (m_size + 1 == MAX_SIZE + 1)
        {
            throw StackOverflowException();
        }
        m_array[++m_top] = _item;
        ++m_size;
    }

    T pop()
    {
        if(m_top != 0)
        {
            --m_size;
            T item =  m_array[m_top];
            --m_top;
            return item;
        }
        throw StackEmptyException();
    }

    T peek() const
    {
        if (m_size == 0) throw StackEmptyException();
        T item = m_array[m_top];
        return item;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return m_size == 0;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }
private:
    T* m_array;
    size_t m_size;
    int m_top;
};
```

The unit tests that cause a heap corruption.

```cpp
        TEST_METHOD(CustomStackPopException)
        {
            Stack<int> stack;
            Assert::ExpectException<StackEmptyException>([&] { stack.pop(); });
        }

        TEST_METHOD(CustomStackPeekException)
        {
            Stack<int> stack;
            Assert::ExpectException<StackEmptyException>([&] { int a = stack.peek(); });
        }

        TEST_METHOD(CustomStackOverflowException)
        {
            Stack<int> stack;
            const auto functor = [&]
            {
                for(auto i = 0; i <= Stack<int>::MAX_SIZE; ++i)
                {
                    stack.push(i);
                }
            };
            Assert::ExpectException<StackOverflowException>(functor);
        }
```

When it reaches the first of those tests, it will throw a popup warning saying:

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block(#279) at 0x0000020298CBC60.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

I've tried making the stack objects on the heap, but that results in the same error.

Comment: Where is your `Stack` user-defined assignment operator?  Your class is not safely copyable without it.  `Stack& operator=(const Stack&)` -- that's the function that needs to be implemented to complete the "rule of 3".

Comment: Correct, I was going to implement the Rule of Five but wanted to fix this issue before.

Comment: `m_size` and `m_top` always have the same value. (One of them is unnecessary, since you want the top index to be one less than the number of elements.)

Comment: As pointed out by @VladFromMoscow, the push method is accessing memory outside its allocated memory, which causes memory corruption in the `CustomStackOverflowException` test. And memory corruption is often unseen until you try to delete it. This might be your problem.

Comment: @Styn -- A missing user-defined assignment operator can also cause heap corruption.  Those `TEST_METHOD`'s are not standard macros, thus all possibilities as to why you're getting heap corruption are on the table.

Comment: Just curious, other than being cryptic and coding more keystrokes, what is the point of checking things like `if (m_size + 1 > MAX_SIZE)` ?  Is the a valid reason why you wouldn't just code `if (m_size == MAX_SIZE)` ? For that matter, I don't understand the current reason for the very existence of `m_size` in the first place. *Everywhere* in this code, where you increment one, you increment the other (eventually); where you decrement one you decrement the other (eventually). As near as I can see, `m_size` existence is dubious at-best.

Comment: @Styn why handroll stack yourself ? theres already one in STL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a combination of users, the problem has been fixed. It was the push function that caused an error.

The push function has been changed from:

```cpp
  void push(T _item)
    {
        if (m_size + 1 == MAX_SIZE + 1)
        {
            throw StackOverflowException();
        }
        m_array[++m_top] = _item;
        ++m_size;
    }
```

To:

```cpp
    void push(T _item)
    {
        if (m_size == MAX_SIZE)
        {
            throw StackOverflowException();
        }
        m_array[m_size] = _item;
        ++m_size;
        ++m_top;
    }
```

The constructor has been changed from:

```cpp
    Stack() : m_array(new T[MAX_SIZE]), m_size(0), m_top(0) {};
```

to

```cpp
    Stack() : m_array(new T[MAX_SIZE]), m_size(0), m_top(-1) {};
```

Now size and top are not the same anymore, and `m_top` actually points to the top of the stack.

Comment: Since the top of the stack is always `m_size - 1`, I suggest to only use `m_size`. This will minimize the risk of errors and simplify the code.

Answer (score 3):

This member function

```
void push(T _item)
{
    if (m_size + 1 == MAX_SIZE + 1)
    {
        throw StackOverflowException();
    }
    m_array[++m_top] = _item;
    ++m_size;
}
```

is already incorrect. Let's assume that MAX_SIZE is equal to 1 and m_size is equal to 0. In this case m_size + 1 is not equal to MAX_SIZE + 1 and there is writtem

```
    m_array[1] = _item;
```

outside the allocated array.

**Edit:** after you changed the method the following way

```
  void push(T _item)
    {
        if (m_size + 1 > MAX_SIZE)
        {
            throw StackOverflowException();
        }
        m_array[++m_top] = _item;
        ++m_size;
    }
```

after I pointed out a problem with it actually the method has the same problem. In fact you cnahged nothing.

Also your stack does not fill the item with the index 0. So in the constructor

```
Stack(const Stack<T>& _other)
{
    m_array = new T[MAX_SIZE];
    for(auto i = 0; i < _other.size(); ++i)
    {
        m_array[i] = _other.m_array[i];
    }
    m_size = _other.size();
    m_top = _other.m_top;
}
```

there is an access of the item with indeterminate value at the position 0

The member function push should be defined like

```
void push( const T &_item)
{
    if (m_size == MAX_SIZE)
    {
        throw StackOverflowException();
    }
    m_array[m_top++] = _item;
    ++m_size;
}
```

and other member functions should be changed with accordance with the member function push.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited it and updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Styn It si a bad idea to change a question such a way after appearing an answer that shows a problem.

Comment: Apologies, I have reverted the change.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the allocation number

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block(#279) at 0x0000020298CBC60.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

Then somewhere at startup insert

```
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(279);
```

That will show you where the memory is allocated and should give a big hint as to where the corruption is.

### Why handroll it yourself ?

Do not implement `stack` yourself

STL already have that container

```
template <class T>
using my_stack = std::stack< T, std::vector<T> >;
```

Comment: @engf-010 I disagree. I think this is one of the reasons the language isn't as popular as it perhaps could be. On the same token - you don't have to be a mechanic to drive a car.

Comment: you're literally the first one to disagree that practice is not good. Many C++ learning books contain implementations of a string/vector/stack/queue/etc just to get experience how to do things. Besides that ,the standard solution may not be adequat of what one needs.

Comment: It's good practice voor noobies to implement versions of widely used datastructures just to get the 'feeling'.

Comment: @engf-010 -- And the risk of getting the "feel" is having new C++ students drop C++ and go to other languages, where they actually see concrete programs being built and in action.  Who wants to spend their time learning how to write a vector class or linked list (which to this day, I have yet to see a C++ student get it done correctly), when they could be getting programming assignments that actually do something tangible?  It's not as if the C++ write themselves if the student uses STL -- they still need to put together the logic.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Your not completely wrong and I partially agree. Using STL in C++ is a must. But implementing linked lists is IMO a requirement. That some student can't do it, says more about the students and their teachers than it is valid argument. I can do it ,so it's not like rocket-science.